# System.exit(0) in Android Wear Watchface?

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I've read that using `System.exit(0)` is frowned upon when it comes to Java and Android, but so far I can find no alternative for what I'm trying to accomplish. **To be clear, this is for a Watchface, which is simply a service extending `CanvasWatchFaceService`. I cannot call `finish()` in this case. I've also tried `stopService` and `startService` with no success.**

**The issue I'm trying to solve:** It's well known that changing timezones on your device will not be reflected on a watchface unless it is restarted. In my testing, I found that `System.currentTimeMillis()` quite literally does not respond to timezone changes in Android Wear. The watchface must be restarted in order for it to show the correct time after a timezone change.

So I built a system with the following code:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver timeChangeReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if (!restarting) {
            if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED)) {
                if (upSeconds >= 15) {
                    System.exit(0);
                } else {
                    restarting = true;
                    int delay = ((15 - upSeconds) * 1000);

                    new CountDownTimer(delay, delay) {
                        @Override
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) { }
                        @Override
                        public void onFinish() {
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                    }.start();
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

The delay is in case a user triggers a time zone change more frequently than 15 seconds at a time. Android Wear seems to detect system exits that are too frequent and replace the watchface with the "Simple" watchface.

It seems to work great, Android Wear automatically boots the watchface back up on exit. But I would eventually like to put this app on the Google Play Store, so I thought I should make sure I'm not playing with fire here.

Comment: Have you seen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257449/system-exit-in-android? Possible dup.

Comment: Thanks for the link! That helps, but it does not fully answer my question. My question is regarding the `CanvasWatchFaceService` in Android Wear specifically.

Comment: All of the code on the [watchface training](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/drawing.html) handles timezone changes just fine. Why do you think you have to exit to get the time to update?

Comment: "It's well known that changing timezones on your device will not be reflected on a watchface unless it is restarted" -- citation, please.

Comment: This is what I was basing that statement off of: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77074.

It has been my experience with all the custom watchfaces I have downloaded as well. However, after seeing ian's comment, I tried one of the standard Google watchfaces and found it does not have the issue. I wonder if the answer lies somewhere in the link he mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't believe I went through all that work when the proper solution was so simple. Thanks [ianhanniballake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1676363/ianhanniballake) for the link!

After looking at the [Analog Watchface Sample](https://developer.android.com/samples/WatchFace/Wearable/src/com.example.android.wearable.watchface/AnalogWatchFaceService.html), I found that all I needed to do was use `mCalendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());`. In many places I was directly comparing the time in milliseconds fetched with `long now = System.currentTimeMillis();`, so I simply did a `now = mCalendar.getTimeInMillis()` to take care of that.

Now the watchface changes time properly when the timezone is changed. I guess the other watchfaces I downloaded did not properly handle this!