# setOnItemClickListener - Doesn't work

Tags: java, android, inputstream, android-button

I have tried to write my first android application. Now I have a problem - setOnItemClickListener is not working. I launched this application on my phone but button is not working. Bellow you can see my code. And I'm ready to answer additional questions if you need. Thanks for your attention.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

static class ElementSong {
    String SongName;        
    ElementSong(String name) {
        this.SongName = name;
   }

}

@Override

protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final EditText searchField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_field);  findViewById(R.id.Search_button);

    final Button SearchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Search_button);
    final ListView item = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.item);
    final ItemsAdapter adapter = new ItemsAdapter();
    final Button SongButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SongButton);
    item.setAdapter(adapter);

    Integer.valueOf(price.getText().toString())));

    InputStream databaseInputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.data);
    BufferedReader br = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;


    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(databaseInputStream));
    try {
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            //will be some code here

        }

        br.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }


    adapter.add(new ElementSong("123"));

    item.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

}




private class ItemsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ElementSong> {
    public ItemsAdapter() {
        super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.item);
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {


        final View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item, null);
        final ElementSong item = getItem(position);
      view.findViewById(R.id.SongButton)).setText(item.SongName);

        return view;

    }

}}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: you haven't set `click listener` on any `Button` instead it is set to your `ListeView`.

Comment: What you want to do exactly

Comment: Use finish() instead of System.exit().see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257449/system-exit-in-android. to know why

Comment: @jackjay yes but my listview contain button. And it can contain many buttons. They all will be created by `adapter.add(new ElementSong("123"));`

Comment: And `System.exit(0);` - this part of code only for button testing. In other part of app - this code working correctly. About my goal i have many same button elements created by adapter.add(new ElementSong("123"));(after it will be creates in loop but now its not important). Now i want be sure - every button will be work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `system.exit(0);` to `finish();`
or any other operation. so you know that the click is performed or not.

Comment: And `System.exit(0);` - this part of code only for button testing. In other part of app - this code working correctly. About my goal i have many same button elements created by adapter.add(new ElementSong("123"));(after it will be creates in loop but now its not important). Now i want be sure - every button will be work correctly.